# Using SQLite transactions I/O Error

Tags: c#, wcf, sqlite, ioerror

I currently have a client / server setup where the client sends data to the server and then the server saves the data to a SQLite database file. To do this I am using transactions which works fine in windows 7 when I run around 30 clients (each client sending data back between 5 - 30 seconds).

When using the same software in Windows XP, I can get/set data multiple times with no problems until I run around 20 clients I start to get Windows Delayed wrote failed errors:
[alt text http://files.me.com/james.ingham/on1qb1](http://files.me.com/james.ingham/on1qb1)

This fires an exception on the server:
[alt text http://files.me.com/james.ingham/hjoodv](http://files.me.com/james.ingham/hjoodv)

I'm assuming this is either something to do with XP or a hardware issue on the machine i'm running XP.

Does anyone have any advice to avoid this? Or if I should just catch the exception and retry saving the data?

Comment: Does this help?
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/330174

Comment: Sorry no, I don't have permissions to change that on the machine I need to run this on. I will test my code in a VM with XP on to see if it's XP or the hardware..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question but this was a hardware issue! Just incase anyone else comes accross it!

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to mention this, but SQLite itself is [not recommended](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) in high concurrent environment. If you have up to 20 clients with transactions lasting 5-30 seconds you will definitely catch a timeout (which is 5 secs in SQLite by default), since SQLite is basically a replacement to *fopen*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is part of a project I'm working on with specific requirements. I had mentioned this at the start but the spec states we must use a db which isn't required to be installed. Also the transactions don't last 5-30 seconds, the data is sent every 5-30 seconds per client. The transactions typically process very quick but it's the hardware (I think) which is slowing this down on specific machines...

Comment: @james.ingham: then, sorry once again. By the way, I wonder why have not you been using MS SQL Compact in context of .Net development (http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact.aspx)

Comment: I haven't tried it but it looks like you need to install it? I have no admin rights to the demo machine, so SQLite was ideal being only a dll I have to include.

Comment: @james.ingham: technically you just need a reference to the corresponding DLL in your project. By default, it is installed in GAC by the msi.